# How cube-y a cuboid is

Tags: geometry

This is a question that's been bugging me for hours.

We have a cuboid $C$ (possibly a cube) with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$. Without loss of generality, assume $a\leq b \leq c$.

**What would be a natural way to measure how close $C$ is to being a cube?** I guess that such a measure, call it $m$, must lie in the interval $(0,1]$. (With $m=1$ iff $C$ is a cube).

Comment: Comment after downvoting so I know what to fix.

Comment: Some function of the variance of $\{a, b, c\}$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang I guess so?

Comment: So any function $f$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Examples are $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang care to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: How about this. Let $d(a,b,c)$ be the distance between $(a,b,c)$ and the line $\{(r,r,r) \mid r >0\}$. Now define $f(a,b,c) = \dfrac{1}{2^{d(a,b,c)}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple formula is to take the volume of the cuboid as a proportion of the cube of the longest side:

$$\operatorname{cubeness}(a, b, c) := \frac{abc}{\max(a, b, c)^3}$$

If you arrange the sides lengths in the order $a \le b \le c$, then this becomes:

$$\operatorname{cubeness}(a, b, c) := \frac{ab}{c^2}$$

Comment: What is the rationale for choosing $с$ over one of the other two sides?

Comment: @Alex: To ensure that the result is between 0 and 1.